# Не работает клик по меню bootsrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Всем привет. Есть такое меню на bootstrape

```
<div class="dropdown">
<a href="/catalog" id="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
КАТАЛОГ ЛЕПНИНЫ
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/kley_dlya_lepniny" itemprop="url">Клей для лепнины</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/gladkie_karnizy" itemprop="url">Гладкие карнизы</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/karnizy_s_risunkom" itemprop="url">Карнизы с рисунком</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/moldingi" itemprop="url">Молдинги</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/rozetki" itemprop="url">Розетки</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/frizy" itemprop="url">Фризы</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/porezki" itemprop="url">Порезки</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/svetovye_karnizy" itemprop="url">Световые карнизы</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/potolochnye_kompozicii" itemprop="url">Потолочные композиции</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/dekorativnye_ramki" itemprop="url">Декоративные рамки</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/ugly" itemprop="url">Углы</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/sredniki" itemprop="url">Средники</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/dekorativnye_kaminy" itemprop="url">Декоративные камины</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/dekorativnye_portaly" v>Декоративные порталы</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/3d_paneli" itemprop="url">3D-панели</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/panno" itemprop="url">Панно</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/kronshteyny" itemprop="url">Кронштейны</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/skulyptury_i_nishi" itemprop="url">Скульптуры и Ниши</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/kariatidy" itemprop="url">Кариатиды</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/kolonny" itemprop="url">Колонны</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/pilyastry" itemprop="url">Пилястры</a></div>
<div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/plintusy" itemprop="url">Плинтусы</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Все работает нормально но вот только по меню

```
<a href="/catalog" id="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    КАТАЛОГ ЛЕПНИНЫ
    </a>
```

Не работает клик. Что делать?

Comment: работает - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/pa42xj62/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте подключили ли Вы jquery и bootstrap.js, все работает:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
  
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="/catalog" id="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  КАТАЛОГ ЛЕПНИНЫ
  </a>
  
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/kley_dlya_lepniny" itemprop="url">Клей для лепнины</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/gladkie_karnizy" itemprop="url">Гладкие карнизы</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/karnizy_s_risunkom" itemprop="url">Карнизы с рисунком</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/moldingi" itemprop="url">Молдинги</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/rozetki" itemprop="url">Розетки</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/frizy" itemprop="url">Фризы</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/porezki" itemprop="url">Порезки</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/svetovye_karnizy" itemprop="url">Световые карнизы</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/potolochnye_kompozicii" itemprop="url">Потолочные композиции</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/dekorativnye_ramki" itemprop="url">Декоративные рамки</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/ugly" itemprop="url">Углы</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/sredniki" itemprop="url">Средники</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/dekorativnye_kaminy" itemprop="url">Декоративные камины</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/dekorativnye_portaly" v>Декоративные порталы</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/3d_paneli" itemprop="url">3D-панели</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/panno" itemprop="url">Панно</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/kronshteyny" itemprop="url">Кронштейны</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/skulyptury_i_nishi" itemprop="url">Скульптуры и Ниши</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/kariatidy" itemprop="url">Кариатиды</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/kolonny" itemprop="url">Колонны</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/pilyastry" itemprop="url">Пилястры</a></div>
  <div><a href="/catalog/katalog_produkcii/plintusy" itemprop="url">Плинтусы</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```